# Best way to keep an information during a PHP Session

Tags: php, web

I am developping a fitness system, so when an user logs in to the system, i have to start a session and keep some information about him in somewhere.

What i am currently doing, is to instantiate an object, called User and storing this object in  a session variable.
Is this a good way to keep the main user information to use it in another pages of the system?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `$_SESSION` superglobal array can satisfy your needs. You can find more information on the following [Location](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

Comment: Yes, it can satisfy my needs, but is it a good way to keep this kind of information? Inside the User object, i have some data that can not be changed, like the user's level inside the system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the session variables are meant for storing data that can be accessed during a session within pages in a web application as long as session_start() is in place for the pages that need to access those data.